# What's the new Watson Discovery service?

Tags: watson-discovery

I just went to Bluemix and saw that there is a new experimental service called **Discovery**. Apparently, it can ingest PDFs, Word Documents, and HTML pages among other file types.

What's the difference between that service and Document Conversion(DC)? Before, I used to convert my documents using DC and then index them in Retrieve and Rank? Is Discovery the merge of Retrieve and Rank and Document Conversion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The IBM Watson™ Discovery Service uses data analysis combined with cognitive intuition to take your unstructured data and enrich it so you can **query** it for the information you need. The service enables you to **ingest and index** content so that you can subsequently use that information to answer queries.

The service is experimental now but the idea is that you will be able to do something similar to what you currently do with Document Conversion and Retrieve and Rank. One of the main benefits is that ingestion and indexing are now managed by the service.

For detailed information, see the [documentation](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/discovery/).

**Note:** I work for IBM Watson

Comment: You should disclose your affiliation as a [worker at IBM](http://stackoverflow.com/users/456564/german-attanasio), otherwise this is essentially spam. The first line is also [copied verbatim from the linked documentation](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/discovery/).

Comment: Good point Aurora, I was just trying to create the tag for future users.

Comment: While the first paragraph is mostly to describe the service, the second paragraph addressed a valid question.

Comment: The first line would probably fit better in a tag wiki than an answer (though I think you do need 1 question created before you can actually edit the tag wiki, so this was necessary). The way the answer was phrased just seemed a lot like spam without context, so it's probably best to be careful with your wording to avoid seeming overly self-promotional.

Comment: [The tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14324321) is almost directly copied and pasted from [this page](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/319713/what-is-the-watson-discovery-service-in-bluemix.html) without attribution, so it's pretty much plagiarism. Please read [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) for details. I suggest rewriting the tag wiki in your own words.

Comment: @Pang I work at IBM and the guy who wrote the answer asked me to add a tag here so It's not plagiarism.

Comment: @GermanAttanasio that could still be considered plagiarism since the work you quote isn't clearly defined (see '[Is it ok to use copied content in tag wikis, if so how do I format it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318337/is-it-ok-to-use-copied-content-in-tag-wikis-if-so-how-do-i-format-it)'). Anyway, writing some original content would make that tag wiki more useful and interesting to others.

Comment: I understand, the original author doesn't have reputation to create tags so that's why I got involve in all this. I will ask him to provide more info and update the wiki

Comment: @GermanAttanasio Can we say that R&R and DC will be deprecated soon?

Comment: We need to wait until the service is deprecated in order to announce it